# Running an android application on top of the lock screen

Tags: android, youtube, android-wake-lock

I am trying to create an alarm clock that plays a Youtube video at a certain time. When I use wakelock, it plays the Youtube video behind the locked screen with this code:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "")
```

I would like the application to wake up the phone and play the Youtube video in front of the lock screen like the native alarm clock application rings in front of the locked screen.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: have you achieved the desired task ?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a system overlay and play the video on it. Create a service and add this code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
               |WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(yourView, params);
    }
```

Dont forget to add `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission inside manifest.

**EDIT**: You can also experiment with `TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT` and `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR` instead of `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.

Comment: Ok, so I created a View class. Inside my view, I have your code and I'm also playing the video after the last line wm.addVideo(yourView, params). I am using google's youtube api to play the video btw. I still have to unlock my phone in order to see the video playing...

Answer (score 2):

You can request than an activity is shown even when the screen is locked out sleeping, add this to onCreate:

```
this.getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```